# C Program: Updating max and min integers without using arrays

Tags: c

I'm experimenting with a simple C program that should prompt user to enter a chosen number of positive integers. I'm having an issue getting the maximum and minimum of the set of integers I input without the use of an array.

The way that I currently have it is that it will update the max and min among the last two entered values. If someone wouldn't mind looking to see what I'm doing wrong, it would be appreciated.

take a look here:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int N ,i, value=0, min=0, max=0, sum=0, oldmin=0, Newmin=0, oldmax=0, Newmax=0;
double mean;

do{

  printf("How many values are to be entered?: ");
  scanf("%d", &N);
  printf("\n");

  if (N>0){

  do{   
     if (N>0){

                                // 1st value updated
     for (i=1;i<=N;i++)
     {   

         printf("Value %d:\n",i);
         scanf("%d", &value);
         sum  = sum+value; 
      }
       mean = (double)sum/(double)N;

      //max
         if(oldmax<Newmax){
            max = Newmax;
         }
         else max = oldmax;

      //min
        if(oldmin>Newmin){
            min = Newmin;
         }
         else min = oldmin;

  }

  else printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
  }
  while(N<0);
      printf("\nThe minimum value is %d, the maximum value is %d, and the average value is %.2lf.",min,max,mean);

      }else printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
  } while(N<0);

return 0;}
```

Comment: I don't think you need oldmax, oldmin / newmax, newmin, you can do it using max and min and always comparing them against value.

Comment: Also could you give us the entry data and the output you are getting?

Comment: Please format the code properly before posting.

Comment: @bruno, oh no, that was an accident! All is good. Thanks again!

Comment: ok, you welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some remarks :

- you need to set the min/max value from *value* in the same loop you do `sum  = sum+value;` , this is the reason of your problem about min/max
- check the scanf result to be sure a number was enter
- `if (N>0){ do{ if (N>0){` so two check but *N* never change
- `if (N > 0)  { do { ... } while (N<0); }` that has no sense
- the embedded loops have no sense, only 1 loop is needed

A proposal removing the problems :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int N;

   fprintf(stderr, "How many values are to be entered?: ");
   if ((scanf("%d", &N)  != 1) || (N <= 0))
     printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
   else {
     int i, min, max, sum = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
       int value;

       fprintf(stderr, "Value %d:\n",i);
       if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
         printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
         return -1;
       }
       sum  = sum+value; 
       if (i == 0) {
         min = max = value;
       }
       else {
         if (value < min)
           min = value;
         if (value > max)
           max = value;
       }
     }

     printf("\nThe minimum value is %d, the maximum value is %d, and the average value is %.2lf\n",
            min,max, (double)sum/(double)N);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
How many values are to be entered?: 3
Value 0:
1
Value 1:
2
Value 2:
3

The minimum value is 1, the maximum value is 3, and the average value is 2.00
```

I used *fprintf* to flush the message with a \n, and I set the first *min* and *max* value on the first turn to not have to use the MIN_INT MAX_INT may be not defined for you

Comment: Why do you print the prompt to `stderr`, but send error messages to `stdout`?  That looks backwards to me.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes I can also send error messages on _stderr_ to be consistent, the problem is the _fflush _on _stdout_ may not work

Comment: But you didn't write `fflush()` anywhere in the code.  If you're saying that `stdout` won't necessarily flush automatically when it gets a newline, well that's true for any stream, and the right thing to do is to call `fflush()` properly.

Comment: @TobySpeight the original code don't print message ended ny a \n, I just respected that, personaly I always end by a \n to force the flush ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(oldmax<Newmax){
```

Don't compare newmax and oldmax. Compare `max` and `value`. Same with `min`.

I'm not even sure about the purpose of `Newmax` and `oldmax`. Remove these variables all-together, as it will just confuse you.

Just use min, max, and value. It will sort out.